# Set ports for ssh to connect to remote Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh

My Linux laptop is on Verizon HomeFusion internet service and I am trying to configure so that I can SSH to a remote Raspberry Pi (through its router) that is using the Virgin mobile service.

Seems my meager understanding of SSH and ports is inadequate.

I have set up a reserved local IP on the Pi router and have forwarded a port to it (PiPort).

Verizon blocks the normal SSH port, 22, so I understand that I need to use a different SSH port (by editing `ssh.conf` and `sshd.conf`). These are my questions:

1) Does the SSH port on the local end (my laptop) need to be the same SSH port on the remote end (Pi) ?

2) Does the SSH port on the remote end (Pi) need to be the same port that is forwarded to the Pi local IP (i.e. remote SSH port = remote forwarded port)?

3) Do I use the `ssh` command:
 `ssh -L local port:remote computer:remote port user@remote ip`?

Answer (score 3):

1. **No.** You are connecting from your laptop to the Pi, not the other way round. Therefore, what matters are the remote ports on the router and on the Pi.
2. **Not necessarily.** You probably can configure your remote router to forward connections on router port X to a different port Y on the Pi. This depends on your particular router's capabilities, but most routers available today should support this.
3. **No.** You use `ssh -p remoteRouterPort user@remoteRouterIP` .

Comment: ok, suppose the (remote) pi local ip (192.168.x.x) is mapped to the remote router port 22 and the pi default ssh port is unchanged ( 22 )

should the following ssh to the pi  work ?
  
ssh -p 22 pi@108.102.x.y     --where 108.102.x.y is the remote router's public ip (and I don't need to append ":22" to the 108.102.x.y" ?

Comment: Yes.  However, if I'm understanding you correctly, the ISP has blocked port 22 - so you won't be able to connect to port 22 on the router (and if you can, you don't need to specify the port at all, as 22 is the default).